# ASP.NET MVC Routing Issue - The view 'Marketing' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something obvious, but here's what's happening.

I added a custom route to my RouteConfig.cs file, as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LibraryCategoryList",
    url: "Library/List/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "List", id = "Marketing" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "BFRDP.Controllers" }
);
```

I have a controller named Library with an action List, as follows:

```
public ActionResult List(string id)
{
    return View(id);
}
```

My List view is at ~/Views/Library/List.cshtml.

When I try to go to http://localhost:49591/Library/List/Marketing, I get the error:

> The view 'Marketing' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Library/Marketing.aspx ~/Views/Library/Marketing.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Marketing.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Marketing.ascx ~/Views/Library/Marketing.cshtml ~/Views/Library/Marketing.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Marketing.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Marketing.vbhtml

(And yes, I do have            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); in the Application_Start method in my global.asax.cs file.)

What in the world am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Laurie

Comment: There's no need for the LibraryCategoryList route. The second route will work just the same for a request to 'Library/List/Marketing'.

Comment: Your using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460352(v=vs.118).aspx) of the `View` method - i.e. specifying the view name. If you want to pass the value "Marketing" as a model to the `List.cshtml` view, then use `return View((object)id);` - i.e. [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492930(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The framework is matching the url to the first route defined, namely LibraryCategoryList. According to this route, the id parameter is equal to "Marketing". So in your action method the return statement becomes the equivalent of:

```
return ("Marketing");
```

in this format "Marketing" becomes the name of the view to return. The framework will look for a view with this name (Marketing.cshtml) in the Library folder than in the shared folder under views. If it does not find one, it gives you that error. So either define a Marketing view under the Library folder or return another view or change the code to:

```
return ("List");
```